# What is the difference between done and complete options in the jquery animate method

Tags: jquery

Today when I was reading new features of the jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method in the options of it I faced two options that I think have the same action.

These options are `done` and `complete`. According to docs they are functions that run when the animation completes.

```
complete
Type: Function()
A function to call once the animation is complete.
```

and :

```
done
Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd )
A function to be called when the animation completes (its Promise object is resolved). (version added: 1.8)
```

Now my question is what is the difference between the two?

Comment: `done()` is a common jQuery method that works with promises, and as `animate()` now returns a promise it can be used with `done()`, just like any other promise, and you can even use `done()` with multiple animations to see when they are all done, while the other one is just a regular callback built into the `animate()` method.

Comment: @adeneo that's great but could you give examples of use?

Comment: It's a simple example, but when an animation completes the callback is called. The same thing happens with the promise, which will be resolved when the animation is complete, but promises can be used in many other ways as well, with methods like $.when(), $.then etc. -> http://jsfiddle.net/kFvmr/

Comment: The thee options `done`, `fail` and `complete` reflect the `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.complete()` methods of jQuery promises, and internally that is exactly what they are. `done` is triggered on successful completion, `fail` is triggered "when the animation fails to complete" (the documentation could be better on this point), and `complete` is triggered in either case, after either `done` or `fail` (if specified).

Comment: At least that's what I thought before I noticed there's also an `always` option. Is this synonymous with `complete`? This area of the documentation needs a serious makeover. Unfortunately I don't have the time or energy to run tests right now.

Comment: @adeneo I suggest you add your comments as an answer, so this question can be properly answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery uses promise which means at the time of done JavaScript can go to next function from promise.

Let's say you have written go to foo and go to bar functions. JQuery will start second one after first started execution irrespective of completion of first.

So when you implement promise, it will wait for previous to complete.

Finally in your case, complete will be called once done is done :). So if you want to process once animation is completed and again do some tricks when first trick is completed write it in complete.

Comment: Late answer (1 year after), and would gain some formatting, it's hard to read like this.

Answer (score 2):

done() is global across the entire of jQuery and fires based on all events within the promise being completed, regardless of if they are queued or async.

Check promises out on jquery's website: [jQuery Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Example from documentation:

```js
var effect = function() {
  return $("div").fadeIn(800).delay(1200).fadeOut();
};

$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("p").append(" Started... ");

  $.when(effect()).done(function() {
    $("p").append(" Finished! ");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go</button>
<p>Ready...</p>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: one important thing to realize is `done` was introduced in 1.6 and `complete` for animations presumably has always been there as long as animations have been. so `promise` and `done` are just a more modern consistent way to do things, whether animations or just regular callbacks

Answer (score 0):

♠♠ *brief answer* :

all the codes you write in done (async or not) run first and when they are completed then the codes in complete will run

you can also use two arguments in done function while the complete function doesn't accept any argumetn

♠♠ *detailed answer* :

there is two difference between done and complete:

**1-** done have time priority to complete so all the codes you write in done (async or not) run first and when they are completed then the codes in complete will run

for example, in the following code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashkan_codecman/x0jqL9my/)) we have an animation with both done and complete functions, when animation completed ,the **done** function make background-color of div **blue** and the **complete** function make background-color of div **red**:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#d_1').click(function () {
    $(this).animate
    (
        {
        width: '200px'
      },
      {
        duration: 800,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).css({
                    backgroundColor: 'red'
                });
        },
        done: function () {
            $(this).css({
                    backgroundColor: 'blue'
                });
        }
      }
    )
  });
})
```

as you can see the final background-color is red which was set in complete function.

**2-** done and complete are functions but complete can't accept any arguments while done can have two arguments (from [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)):

> done
>
> Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd )
>
> A function to be called when the animation on an element completes (its Promise object is resolved). (version added: 1.8)

the "promise animation" is the same "fx" prototype of jQuery animation and "jumpedToEnd" is An auxiliary parameter which means that If an animation is interrupted or unsuccessful (its Promise object is rejected), it automatically jumps to the end.